# Método de repulsão baseado no modelo de Helbing

Tags: java, matemática, física

Estou desenvolvendo um simulador de multidões seguindo o modelo de Forças Sociais de Helbing, só que estou tendo um problema no momento que acontece a colisão entre os agentes.

Quando acontece a colisão o método de repulsão é chamado para calcular a nova posição para o agente A e agente B, só que quando calculo a nova posição ele está dando uma posição muito deslocada da posição onde ocorreu a colisão ou seja meus agentes estão dando saltos para trás, lados e etc.

O algoritmo devia funcionar fluido igual [esse vídeo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylJG0gNLpNE) ou [esse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMmDoyRnWL4).

Segue meu código de repulsão´:

```
    private double SIGMA = 0.3f; //a distância no qual o efeito territorial será válido
    private double VELOCIDADE_MAX = 1.34f;
    private double LAMBDA = 0.2f;
    private double FORCACORPO = 3f; //12
    private double FORCAFRICCAO = 3f;
    private double LIMITE = 2.0f;
    private double R = 0.2f;
    private double T = 0.5f;
    private double EPSILON = 0.55f;
    private double intensidadeInteracao = 2.5;  

public void RepulsiveEffect(Humano a, Humano b, int k) {
        Point2D vDistancia = new Point2D(a.getCx() - b.getCx(), a.getCy() - b.getCy());

        //Distancia dos pedestres entre seus centros de massa
        //Distance of pedestrians between their centers of mass
        double distanciaAB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vDistancia.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(vDistancia.getY(), 2));

        //Normalizacao do vetor
        //Vector normalization
        Point2D vNormalizado = new Point2D(vDistancia.getX() / distanciaAB, vDistancia.getY() / distanciaAB);
        double rab = a.getRaio() + b.getRaio();
        double forcaRepulsiva = intensidadeInteracao * (Math.pow(Math.E, (rab - distanciaAB)) / SIGMA);
        double anisA = 1.0f;
        double anisB = 1.0f;

        //Fatores de Direcao de a
        //Direction Factors of a
        Point2D direcaoADestino = new Point2D(a.getDestino().getX() - a.getCx(), a.getDestino().getY() - a.getCy());
        double distanciaADestino = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(direcaoADestino.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(direcaoADestino.getY(), 2));
        double cosa = (-direcaoADestino.getX() * vDistancia.getX() - direcaoADestino.getY() * vDistancia.getY()) / (distanciaADestino * distanciaAB);
        anisA = LAMBDA + (1 - LAMBDA) * (1 + cosa) * 0.5;

        //Fatores de Direcao de b
        //Direction Factors of b
        Point2D direcaoBDestino = new Point2D(b.getDestino().getX() - b.getCx(), b.getDestino().getY() - b.getCy());
        double distanciaBDestino = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(direcaoBDestino.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(direcaoBDestino.getY(), 2));
        double cosb = (-direcaoBDestino.getX() * vDistancia.getX() + direcaoBDestino.getY() * vDistancia.getY()) / (distanciaBDestino * distanciaAB);
        anisB = LAMBDA + (1 - LAMBDA) * (1 + cosb) * 0.5;

        //Atualizacao da Velocidade de a
        //Speed update of a
        double nxa = atual.get(a.getID()).getX() + (forcaRepulsiva * vNormalizado.getX()) * anisA;
        double nya = atual.get(a.getID()).getY() + (forcaRepulsiva * vNormalizado.getY()) * anisA;
        atual.set(a.getID(), new Point2D(nxa, nya));

        //Atualizacao da Velocidade de B (subtracao pois vetor normal é oposto)
        //Speed update of B (Subtraction since normal vector is opposite)
        double nxb = atual.get(b.getID()).getX() - (forcaRepulsiva * vNormalizado.getX()) * anisB;
        double nyb = atual.get(b.getID()).getY() - (forcaRepulsiva * vNormalizado.getY()) * anisB;
        atual.set(b.getID(), new Point2D(nxb, nyb));

        //Colisao
        //Colision
        if (k == 1) {
            //Forca corpo
            //Force body
            double k1 = FORCACORPO * (rab - distanciaAB);
            nxa = atual.get(a.getID()).getX();
            nya = atual.get(a.getID()).getY();

            nxa += k1 * vNormalizado.getX();
            nya += k1 * vNormalizado.getY();

            atual.set(a.getID(), new Point2D(nxa, nya));

            nxb = atual.get(b.getID()).getX();
            nyb = atual.get(b.getID()).getY();
            nxb -= k1 * vNormalizado.getX();
            nyb -= k1 * vNormalizado.getY();

            atual.set(b.getID(), new Point2D(nxb, nyb));

            //Forca friccao de a
            //Force friction of a
            double kba = 1.0f;
            Point2D tab = new Point2D(-vNormalizado.getX(), vNormalizado.getY());
            Point2D vba = new Point2D(b.getVetorVelocidade().getX() - a.getVetorVelocidade().getX(), b.getVetorVelocidade().getY() - a.getVetorVelocidade().getY());
            double vbaf = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vba.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(vba.getY(), 2));

            kba = FORCAFRICCAO * (rab - distanciaAB) * vbaf;
            kba = FORCAFRICCAO * (rab - distanciaAB) * (a.getVetorVelocidade().getX() * tab.getX() + a.getVetorVelocidade().getY() * tab.getY());

            nxa = atual.get(a.getID()).getX();
            nya = atual.get(a.getID()).getY();

            nxa += kba * tab.getX();
            nya += kba * tab.getY();
            atual.set(a.getID(), new Point2D(nxa, nya));

            //Forca fricção de b
            //Force friction of a
            double kab = 1.0f;
            Point2D tba = new Point2D(vNormalizado.getX(), -vNormalizado.getY());
            Point2D vab = new Point2D(a.getVetorVelocidade().getX() - b.getVetorVelocidade().getX(), a.getVetorVelocidade().getY() - b.getVetorVelocidade().getY());
            double vabf = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vab.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(vab.getY(), 2));

            kab = FORCAFRICCAO * (rab - distanciaAB) * vabf;
            kab = FORCAFRICCAO * (rab - distanciaAB) * (b.getVetorVelocidade().getX() * tab.getX() + b.getVetorVelocidade().getY() * tab.getY());

            nxb = atual.get(b.getID()).getX();
            nyb = atual.get(b.getID()).getY();

            nxb += kab * tba.getX();
            nyb += kab * tba.getY();
            atual.set(b.getID(), new Point2D(nxb, nyb));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Primeira coisa: qual é a linguagem? Usar um monte de tags de linguagens distintas não vai fazer você obter uma resposta mais rápido, bem pelo contrário só vai confundir quem quer te ajudar. **Segundo**: Coloque o código aqui e não em fontes externas (é possível usar o atalho `Ctrl + K` para formatar o código), melhor ainda, coloque apenas um [mcve] aqui.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pelo feedback Jbueno, sou novo no stackoverflow, nunca postei nada.

Comment: Sim, eu vi que você é novo, por isso as dicas.

Comment: @AlissonPereira você poderia postar o restante do código como, por exemplo, as classes Humano, a variável intensidadeInteracao, etc.?

Comment: @hlucasfranca sim posso sim.

Comment: Segue um Artigo com formulas do modelo de helbing: 
https://www.lume.ufrgs.br/bitstream/handle/10183/8125/000568310.pdf?sequence=1 - Pagina 21, e tambem a classe humano: https://pastebin.com/fgu8YTv6

Comment: @AlissonPereira mesmo com o código da classe Humano, o código não compila, por falta de outras dependências. Tente postar o código aqui no stackoverflow ou crie um repositório no github, se possível

Comment: @hlucasfranca Acho mais facil eu mandar por inbox, pois é um trabalho de conclusão de curso.